# The number that counts

Tags: knowledge, story

The kids were discussing fiercely during the school break (ah, those were the times!). The subject: Bragging about who can count up to the highest number.

John said "I can do 20".
Jolene said "I know up to 50!".
Miles said "I know up to a hundred!".

Little Marie felt sad, she was the youngest and not only had she studied only up to 10, but she was bad at it too. To her great gladness, at that time, her cousin, a science university grad, just strolled up to say hi!

"Big Cousin Nicola, please tell us how high you can count"!

"Well Marie, I'll tell you a more interesting thing instead - I know a number that can itself count"!

What is that number?

Hint:

> The associated knowledge science is not math. Also, no lateral thinking (at least on word level).

Hint2:

> The associated knowledge is not programming. Else, any program that implements counting could be interpreted as a number and be the solution.

Hint 3(strong):

> 3 digits

Comment: It seems to me that without the hints, this question is not well-defined enough. Which means the hints aren't really hints. They're vital parts of the puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>This is a stupid answer I spent way too much time searching for. I know this isn't the answer.</sub>

---

It is of course

> 4308900011000

because

> When using this number as the source code in the well-known and respected esoteric programming language [Numeric Topline](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Numeric_Topline), the program just counts from 1 up to infinity! (well, not really. Probably up to 2^31-1).
>
>  The instructions are:
>  `43` - Reset the count to 0. Solely here because the number (source code) itself can't start with a 0
>  `08` - Start of an infinite loop
>  `90001` - Add 1 to the count. +- determined by set polarity, which is positive by default. Count is 0 by default, so we start at 1 after this instruction.
>  `10` - Print out the current numeric count
>  `00` - Marks the end of the loop. Not meaning the program stops there, just that everything between `08` and `00` is looped forever.

Side note

> First number `43` can of course be replaced with other statements that do nothing in our context, like `47`, which sets the polarity to positive (which it already is by default)
>
>  Furthermore, if we use ASCII-output instead of numerical and "create" the numbers with ASCII by ourselves, we could make this program count much higher. But I can't be bothered for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that what you're thinking of is

> The [Champernowne Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant)

Reasoning

> The number is obtained by concatenating the decimal representation of successive integers after the decimal point so, in a way, it represents counting. Also, it is known to be transcendental.

Comment: Nice one. Added a hint explaining why it's not.

Comment: If you have to add a "hint" to invalidate an answer, that's a clarification, not a hint.

Answer (score 2):

> A [self-descriptive number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-descriptive_number) counts its digits.

Comment: Nice try, but looking for a more general count.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really weird guess, but

> 315211420

Explanation:

> It is A1Z26 for "count".

Comment: Shucks, why did this recieve a delete vote?

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

> 128

Explanation:

> 128 is rebus for "One to [infinity](https://www.dictionary.com/e/pop-culture/infinity-symbol/)".

Answer (score 0):

Four as it counts four letters? (as the only one between 1 and 10)

Comment: "it counts 4 letters"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the answer is

> 123

Since if you say the digits aloud,

> one, two, three ... it sounds like counting

Why not

> 1234 ?

Because of the third hint, and of the way children describe counting.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is:

> 212

This is because

> The number is 2, and it counts itself: 1, 2.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

> 121

Because it is

> 1 2, and 2 1's